Almalinux - Extending root partition from 4 GiB to 14 GiB
I am trying to extend the disk space on an AlmaLinux server (running on a VM).
The goal is to add unallocated 10.00 GiB to the root partition (dev/sda2).
What is the best way to do this without losing any data?
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   310G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     4G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     1G  0 part /tmp
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0 294.5G  0 part /var/lib/mysql
sdb      8:16   0   127G  0 disk
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 from

Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 333GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   primary   ext4         boot
 2      538MB   4833MB  4295MB  primary   xfs
 3      4833MB  5907MB  1074MB  primary   xfs
 4      5907MB  322GB   316GB   extended
 5      5908MB  322GB   316GB   logical   xfs

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   primary   ext4         boot
2      538MB   4833MB  4295MB  primary   xfs
3      4833MB  5907MB  1074MB  primary   xfs
4      5907MB  322GB   316GB   extended
5      5908MB  322GB   316GB   logical   xfs
322GB   333GB   10.7GB            Free Space



The goal is to add unallocated 10.00 GiB to the root partition (dev/sda2). What is the best way to do this without losing any data?

Your problem is that the unallocated space is at the end of the drive, while your partition is in the middle. You can generally only ever expand a partition to unallocated space adjacent to the partition. To overcome this, you have to use something like LVM (or a filesystem with subvolumes such as BTRFS).
In your scenario the proper way to do it is to perform a full backup, re-partition, reinstall system, and restore from backup. You can try to move partitions in gparted from a live system, but it carries the risk of data loss.

In my case, GParted doesn't allow moving partitions...

Have you booted a live system? You can't move mounted partitions.

Yes, I booted live system but I was not able to move partitions.

Then reinstall your system and restore from backup.
